# How to set Memory limits to elasticsearch in Debian?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to increase the memory limits of elasticsearch in debian..Please let me know in which file should i make changes to increase it's memory..also how to check whether the memory limits are set or not...as I was getting an error something like:
Too many Files Open
Plz help...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is file like /etc/init.d/elasticsearch...and it contains the code like
ES_HOME=/usr/local/elasticsearch
ES_MIN_MEM=256m
ES_MAX_MEM=2g
DAEMON=$ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch
NAME=elasticsearch
DESC=elasticsearch
PID_FILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
LOG_DIR=/var/log/$NAME
DATA_DIR=/var/lib/$NAME
WORK_DIR=/tmp/$NAME
CONFIG_FILE=/etc/$NAME/elasticsearch.yml
...please let me know if i need to set the max and min memory limits here? also where to set the max number of open files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lol, my rep is too low simply answer: but I just want to confirm that the file /etc/init.d/elasticsearch contains startup info. MIN and MAX_MEM are min and max heap size

I'm pretty sure if you're on systemd the equivalent file will be under /etc/default/

Restart elasticsearch for your settings to take effect. If you're on systemd: sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch. If it fails to restart due to bad settings, sudo systemctl status elasticsearch

This answer discusses a few other options
[How to change Elasticsearch max memory size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132719/how-to-change-elasticsearch-max-size)

Answer (score 4):

The best way to set the memory is to set the ES_HEAP_SIZE parameter, and let that dictate the min and max values.

For Ubuntu just open the elasticsearch file in /etc/default:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/elasticsearch
```

and make sure that the following line is either set or uncommented, and set it to half of your total ram:

```
ES_HEAP_SIZE=4g
```

Then save your file, and restart elasticsearch:

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

For more info on setting the heap size you can check out [this article here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html). Granted the guide tells you to just create an environmental variable using the export command; however, that did not work for me, though the /etc/default/elasticsearch file will work, even after a restart.

Note: do not set the heap size over 32Gb. Using decimals for your heap_size will break Elasticsearch. If you need to use partial Gb's then use Mb like this: `ES_HEAP_SIZE=3750m`. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Rajni is absolutely right.  I had the same question as OP and found all of the values set within the service script near the beginning:

```
ES_HOME=/opt/elasticsearch
ES_MIN_MEM=256m
ES_MAX_MEM=2g
DAEMON=$ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch
NAME=elasticsearch
DESC=elasticsearch
PID_FILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
LOG_DIR=/var/log/$NAME
DATA_DIR=/var/lib/$NAME
WORK_DIR=/tmp/$NAME
CONFIG_FILE=$ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

update the JVM heap size in jvm.options file

Stop the elasticsearch

File Path: /etc/elasticsearch/

Command: sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options

=> Uncomment and update the JVM heap size:

[image]