# How to change Elasticsearch max memory size

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Apache server with a default configuration of Elasticsearch and everything works perfectly, except that the default configuration has a max size of 1GB.

I don't have such a large number of documents to store in Elasticsearch, so I want to reduce the memory.

I have seen that I have to change the `-Xmx` parameter in the Java configuration, but I don't know how.

I have seen I can execute this:

```
bin/ElasticSearch -Xmx=2G -Xms=2G
```

But when I have to restart Elasticsearch this will be lost.

Is it possible to change max memory usage when Elasticsearch is installed as a service?

Comment: What operating system and version? Elasticsearch version? How did you install Elasticsearch?

Comment: You might want to lower the number of replicas and shards since there is no upside of having them on a 1 node setup, add this to /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yaml: 

`index.number_of_shards: 1
index.number_of_replicas: 0`

This way you save on memory and cpu by not doing unneccessary work.

Answer (score 171):

In **ElasticSearch >= 5** the documentation has [changed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html), which means none of the above answers worked for me.

I tried changing `ES_HEAP_SIZE` in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` and in `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch`, but when I ran `ps aux | grep elasticsearch` the output still showed:

```
/usr/bin/java -Xms2g -Xmx2g # aka 2G min and max ram
```

**I had to make these changes in:**

`/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`

```
# Xms represents the initial size of total heap space
# Xmx represents the maximum size of total heap space

-Xms1g 
-Xmx1g 
# the settings shipped with ES 5 were: -Xms2g
# the settings shipped with ES 5 were: -Xmx2g
```

Comment: And for Elasticsearch 5.2 on Mac OS 10.12 I found this file in
`/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/libexec/config/jvm.options`

Comment: I can confirm this works for aws ami instance (installed with RPM), but first set MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited in /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch and bootstrap.memory_lock: true in /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

Comment: This does not work in Windows - the correct answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798845/how-to-set-memory-limit-to-elasticsearch-in-windows

Comment: For homebrew installs, file is in here: `/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`

Comment: This works for Rocky 8 (and the entire EL8 family)

Answer (score 117):

**Updated on Nov 24, 2016**: Elasticsearch 5 apparently has changed the way to configure the JVM. [See this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132719/how-to-change-elasticsearch-max-memory-size/40333263#40333263). The answer below still applies to versions < 5.

tirdadc, thank you for pointing this out in your comment below.

---

I have a pastebin page that I share with others when wondering about memory and ES.  It's worked OK for me: http://pastebin.com/mNUGQCLY.  I'll paste the contents here as well:

References:

https://github.com/grigorescu/Brownian/wiki/ElasticSearch-Configuration
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/installation/

Edit the following files to modify memory and file number limits. These instructions assume Ubuntu 10.04, may work on later versions and other distributions/OSes. (**Edit**: This works for Ubuntu 14.04 as well.)

**/etc/security/limits.conf**:

```
elasticsearch - nofile 65535
elasticsearch - memlock unlimited
```

**/etc/default/elasticsearch (on CentOS/RH: /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch )**:

```
ES_HEAP_SIZE=512m
MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535
MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited
```

**/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml**:

```
bootstrap.mlockall: true
```

Comment: This looks good. I also have the following advice about determining what ES_HEAP_SIZE should be:
The rule of thumb is that the ElasticSearch heap should have around 50% of the available memory on the machine. ElasticSearch uses system caches heavily, so you should leave enough memory for them.
(from http://asquera.de/opensource/2012/11/25/elasticsearch-pre-flight-checklist/ )

Comment: In CentOS, I see the configs that you mentioned under `/etc/default` sits under `/etc/sysconfig'

Comment: On CentOS `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch` is the appropriate place to make these changes. The RPM even provides a default version of this file there too.

Comment: This is no longer applicable for Elasticsearch 5, you need this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40333263/3102766).

Comment: For a Windows Service, also be aware of registry settings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128620/elasticsearch-reports-default-heap-memory-size-after-setting-environment-variabl

Comment: This looks good, but I put my limits in specifically for elasticsearch user in `/etc/security/limits.d/elasticsearch.conf`

Answer (score 40):

Create a new file with the extension `.options` inside `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options.d` and put the options there. For example:

```
sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options.d/custom.options
```

and put the content there:

```
# JVM Heap Size - see /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options
-Xms2g
-Xmx2g
```

It will set the maximum heap size to 2GB. Don't forget to restart elasticsearch:

```
sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch
```

Now you can check the logs:

```
sudo cat /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log | grep "heap size"
```

You'll see something like so:

… `heap size [2gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]`

[Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/advanced-configuration.html)

Comment: kudos for mentioning the ".options" filename, this was not in documentation and thus working for me, now it is. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks. This worked on Rocky 8, where the previous Centos 7 instructions did not. (Even though the sysconfig file existed)

Comment: Thanks for that. This approach is only recommended by ES.

Comment: In docker, the directory is `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options.d`.

Comment: In Mac/Homebrew, in 2024, using the `elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full` tap, the directory is `/opt/homebrew/etc/elasticsearch`

Answer (score 28):

For anyone looking to do this on Centos 7 or with another system running SystemD, you change it in

```
/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch
```

Uncomment the ES_HEAP_SIZE line, and set a value, eg:

```
# Heap Size (defaults to 256m min, 1g max)
ES_HEAP_SIZE=16g
```

(Ignore the comment about 1g max - that's the default)

Comment: I should add: I tried the approach above on ES 1.7 on CentOS 7, and it had no effect

Comment: @Jonesome not sure what I can suggest - I am running ES 1.7.1 from the ES RPM Package on CentOS 7 and that's the path that this file exists in, and changing ES_HEAP_SIZE works as intended.

Comment: Note for users of EL8 (Rhel, Centos, Rocky, etc). Although sysconfig does exist as per this, changing it does not make the change. The change needs to be made in /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options as per @farahmand's answer instead.

Verification is made by: curl -sS  "localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?h=heap*&v"

Answer (score 15):

Instructions for `ubuntu 14.04`:

`sudo vim /etc/init.d/elasticsearch`

Set

`ES_HEAP_SIZE=512m`

then in:

`sudo vim /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

Set:

`bootstrap.memory_lock: true`

There are comments in the files for more info

Answer (score 11):

Previous answers were insufficient in my case, probably because I'm on Debian 8, while they were referred to some previous distribution.

On **Debian 8** modify the service script normally place in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service`, and add `Environment=ES_HEAP_SIZE=8G` 
just below the other "Environment=*" lines.

Now reload the service script with `systemctl daemon-reload` and restart the service. The job should be done!

Comment: thanks, you save my day! yes, this is the correct procedure for Debian 8

Comment: Is there no other place to configure this but to change a file in `/usr/`?

Comment: Works like a charm on ES 1.7.6 / Ubuntu 16

Answer (score 8):

- Elasticsearch will assign the entire heap specified in jvm.options via the Xms (minimum heap size) and Xmx (maximum heap size) settings.

  - -Xmx12g
  - -Xmx12g
- Set the minimum heap size (Xms) and maximum heap size (Xmx) to be equal to each other.
- Don’t set Xmx to above the cutoff that the JVM uses for compressed object pointers (compressed oops), the exact cutoff varies but is near 32 GB.
- It is also possible to set the heap size via an environment variable

  - ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g" ./bin/elasticsearch
  - ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4000m -Xmx4000m" ./bin/elasticsearch

Comment: Also no more than 50% of the physical RAM

Comment: Hi How i set environment variable like this .Variable name is ES_JAVA_OPTS and value : "-Xms2g -Xmx2g" ./bin/elasticsearch like

Comment: I recommend making the adjustment in the file `jvm.options` 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/important-settings.html#heap-size-settings

Comment: I need something configurable, so environment variables are perfect, but I can't seem to make it work. I have an environment file that I'm passing to docker with --env-file argument, and I tried adding `ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g" ./bin/elasticsearch` there, but that just gives me `Error: Could not find or load main class "-Xms2g`. Any ideas?

Comment: @lovrodoe: see below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78238765/1587329

Answer (score 7):

File path to change heap size `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`

If you are using nano then do `sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options` and update `-Xms` and `-Xmx` accordingly.

(You can use any file editor to edit it)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you use the service wrapper provided in Elasticsearch's Github repository, found at https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-servicewrapper, then the conf file at  elasticsearch-servicewrapper / service / elasticsearch.conf controls memory settings. At the top of elasticsearch.conf is a parameter:

```
set.default.ES_HEAP_SIZE=1024
```

Just reduce this parameter, say to "set.default.ES_HEAP_SIZE=512", to reduce Elasticsearch's allotted memory.

Note that if you use the elasticsearch-wrapper, the ES_HEAP_SIZE provided in elasticsearch.conf OVERRIDES ALL OTHER SETTINGS. This took me a bit to figure out, since from the documentation, it seemed that heap memory could be set from elasticsearch.yml.

If your service wrapper settings are set somewhere else, such as at /etc/default/elasticsearch as in James's example, then set the ES_HEAP_SIZE there.

Comment: what if u don't have any service at all? (ie just run bin/elasticsearch -d)

Comment: [Note: elasticsearch-servicewrapper has been deprecated and much of the functionality added to elasticsearch.](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-servicewrapper)

Comment: @HenleyChiu then just set ES_HEAP_SIZE environment variable before running it. ie `export ES_HEAP_SIZE=1G; bin/elasticsearch -d`

Comment: In the ES 1.7.x stock elasticsearch.conf (the one installed by the rpm on CentOS), there is no set.default at all. Does this approach work on ES 1.7?

Comment: The above answer is misleading. Set ES_HEAP_SIZE in /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch

Answer (score 6):

If you installed ES using the RPM/DEB packages as provided (as you seem to have), you can adjust this by editing the init script (`/etc/init.d/elasticsearch on RHEL/CentOS`). If you have a look in the file you'll see a block with the following:

```
export ES_HEAP_SIZE
export ES_HEAP_NEWSIZE
export ES_DIRECT_SIZE
export ES_JAVA_OPTS
export JAVA_HOME
```

To adjust the size, simply change the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` line to the following:

```
export ES_HEAP_SIZE=xM/xG
```

(where x is the number of MB/GB of RAM that you would like to allocate)

Example:

```
export ES_HEAP_SIZE=1G
```

Would allocate 1GB.

Once you have edited the script, save and exit, then restart the service. You can check if it has been correctly set by running the following:

```
ps aux | grep elasticsearch
```

And checking for the -Xms and -Xmx flags in the java process that returns:

```
/usr/bin/java -Xms1G -Xmx1G
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Don't do it this way. This is not a good place to make these types of changes. This is a giant hack! Might work, but it'll get potentially trashed whenever ES is updated.

Comment: I should add: I tried the approach above on ES 1.7 on CentOS 7, and it had no effect.

Answer (score 4):

In elasticsearch path home dir i.e. typically `/usr/share/elasticsearch`,
There is a config file `bin/elasticsearch.in.sh`.
Edit parameter `ES_MIN_MEM`, `ES_MAX_MEM` in this file to change `-Xms2g`, `-Xmx4g` respectively. 
And Please make sure you have restarted the node after this config change.

Answer (score 4):

Oneliner for Centos 7 & Elasticsearch 7 (2g = 2GB)

```
$ echo $'-Xms2g\n-Xmx2g' > /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options.d/2gb.options
```

and then

```
$ service elasticsearch restart
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using docker-compose to run a ES cluster:

- Open `<your docker compose>.yml` file
- If you have set the `volumes` property, you won't lose anything. Otherwise, you must first move the indexes.
- Look for this value `ES_JAVA_OPTS` under `environment` and change the value in all nodes, the result could be somethig like `"ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g"`
- rebuild all nodes `docker-compose -f <your docker compose>.yml up -d`

Answer (score 1):

If you use windows server, you can change Environment Variable, restart server to apply new Environment Value and start Elastic Service. More detail in [Install Elastic in Windows Server](https://thoaingo07.wordpress.com/2015/04/03/elasticsearch-installation-in-windows-server/)

Answer (score 1):

In elasticsearch 2.x :

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch
```

Go to the block of code

```
# Heap size defaults to 256m min, 1g max
# Set ES_HEAP_SIZE to 50% of available RAM, but no more than 31g
#ES_HEAP_SIZE=2g
```

Uncomment last line like

```
ES_HEAP_SIZE=2g
```

Answer (score 1):

Update elastic configuration in path `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`

```
################################################################
## IMPORTANT: JVM heap size
################################################################
##
## The heap size is automatically configured by Elasticsearch
## based on the available memory in your system and the roles
## each node is configured to fulfill. If specifying heap is
## required, it should be done through a file in jvm.options.d,
## and the min and max should be set to the same value. For
## example, to set the heap to 4 GB, create a new file in the
## jvm.options.d directory containing these lines:
##
## -Xms4g
## -Xmx4g
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html
## for more information
##
################################################################
-Xms1g
-Xmx1g
```

These configs mean you allocate 1GB RAM for elasticsearch service.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ubuntu 15.04+ or any other distro that uses systemd, you can set the max memory size editing the elasticsearch systemd service and setting the max memory size using the ES_HEAP_SIZE environment variable, I tested it using ubuntu 20.04 and it works fine:

```
systemctl edit elasticsearch
```

Add the environement variable ES_HEAP_SIZE with the desired max memory, here 2GB as example:

```
[Service]
Environment=ES_HEAP_SIZE=2G
```

Reload systemd daemon

```
systemd daemon-reload
```

Then restart elasticsearch

```
systemd restart elasticsearch
```

To check if it worked as expected:

```
systemd status elasticsearch
```

You should see in the status `-Xmx2G`:

```
 CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
         └─2868 /usr/bin/java -Xms2G -Xmx2G
```

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Search `7.x` and above, tested with `Ubuntu 20`

1. Create a file in `/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options.d`. The file name must ends with `.options`

   For example `heap_limit.options`
2. Add these lines to the file

   ```
   ## Initial memory allocation

   -Xms1g

   ## Maximum memory allocation

   -Xmx1g
   ```
3. Restart elastic search service

   `sudo service elasticsearch restart`

   or

   `sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch`

Comment: With ES 7.17 you no longer need to specify the heap size at all, it automatically computes it. Note this automatic computation does not work (uses default -Xmx1g) when elasticsearch.yml has deprecated settings node.master=true node.data=true.

Answer (score 0):

window 7 elasticsearch
elastic search memories problem
elasticsearch-7.14.1\config\jvm.options

add  this
-Xms1g
-Xmx1g

elasticsearch-7.14.1\config\elasticsearch.yml

uncomment
bootstrap.memory_lock: true

and pest
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-servicewrapper    download service file  and pest
lasticsearch-7.14.1\bin

bin\elasticsearch.bat  enter

Answer (score 0):

In case you run in the problem describe above when setting via environment variables via systemd:

> I need something configurable, so environment variables are perfect, but I can't seem to make it work. I have an environment file that I'm passing to docker with --env-file argument, and I tried adding ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g" ./bin/elasticsearch there, but that just gives me Error: Could not find or load main class "-Xms2g. Any ideas? –

you need to escape the variables, like so:

```
systemd-escape -- "-Xmx2g -Xms2g"
```

The resulting string should then work as systemd ENVIRONMENT parameter, like so:

```
Environment=ES_JAVA_OPTS=\x2dXmx2g\x20\x2dXms2g
```