# ElasticSearch Increase Memory No Service Wrapper

Tags: elasticsearch

Im running ElasticSearch 1.3.2 on Centos 6.5 with the terminal like so:

```
bin/elasticsearch -console
```

My server has 16GB of RAM. How do I give 8GB of it to ES?

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132719/how-to-change-elasticsearch-max-size) may have the answer but I just couldnt piece it together. Further the [docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html) have only confused me more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its good practice to should keep 50% memory for Elasticsearch Heap Size. As you mentioned you don't have service wrapper. In this case you can assign heap size while starting elasticsearch services.

```
bin/elasticsearch ES_HEAP_SIZE=8000m
```

Comment: UPDATE w/ 2.x make sure to add a -- to ES_HEAP_SIZE