# Elasticsearch reports default heap memory size after setting environment variable

Tags: elasticsearch, memory, jvm, heap-memory

In attempt to increase JVM heap size for Elasticsearch on a Windows box, I defined the following environment variable:

ES_HEAP_SIZE=6g

(The machine has 12G RAM in total).

I have restarted ES and queried its memory usage using _nodes/stat HTTP GET command. However, it seems that it's still using 1GB:

mem: {

```
heap_used_in_bytes: 1032367576,
heap_used_percent: 99,
heap_committed_in_bytes: 1037959168,
heap_max_in_bytes: 1037959168,
...
```

Shouldn't ES adjust its heap memory size after the restart?

Answer (score 10):

From the notes on [running ES as a service on windows](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service-win.html):

> Note that the environment configuration options available during the installation are copied and will be used during the service lifecycle. This means any changes made to them after the installation will not be picked up unless the service is reinstalled.

If you don't want to uninstall and re-install, you can use the service manager to make the change. Run `>service manager`

Then select the 'Java' Tab

[image: Java Tab]

Change the memory pool settings, hit 'Apply' and restart the service.

[image]

Comment: Does this override any previously configured environment variables?

Comment: Yes, the originally configured environment variables are used to configure the service initially. By making changes here, this will override any environment variables.

Answer (score 6):

After I had uninstalled and reinstalled Elasticsearch Windows service, it correctly increased the JVM heap size. Just restarting it without reinstalling the service didn't work.

Comment: This worked!

I am using Windows Server 2012 and I had the same problem (although I was using the ES_MIN_MEM and ES_MAX_MEM environment variables - then I added ES_HEAP_SIZE for good measure). I tried restarting (in a new Administrator Powershell window, to pick up the env changes) to no avail. Using {ES_HOME}\bin\service.bat stop/remove/install/start (as Administrator) successfully changed the memory allocation. It must be picking up the environment variables during the installation rather than at runtime. Thanks for posting your own answer!

Answer (score 0):

For Elastic Search 1.5

One way to do it is to edit the `/bin/elasticsearch.in.sh` file to default to some other value that 1g. For your example, change the `ES_MAX_MEM=1g` for `ES_MAX_MEM=6g`.  After editing, restart Elastic Search and you should be good.

```
#!/bin/sh

ES_CLASSPATH=$ES_CLASSPATH:$ES_HOME/lib/elasticsearch-1.5.0.jar:$ES_HOME/lib/*:$ES_HOME/lib/sigar/*

if [ "x$ES_MIN_MEM" = "x" ]; then
    ES_MIN_MEM=256m
fi
if [ "x$ES_MAX_MEM" = "x" ]; then
    ES_MAX_MEM=6g
fi
if [ "x$ES_HEAP_SIZE" != "x" ]; then
    ES_MIN_MEM=$ES_HEAP_SIZE
    ES_MAX_MEM=$ES_HEAP_SIZE
fi
```

Comment: @jasonrhasss I modified in /bin/elasticsearch.in.sh but it is not effeting in elastic,still it is using 1g only

Comment: @RamRajVasavi did you install via yum or apt-get?  It could be using a different startup script.  Also - are you using version 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid service re-install you can directly change values in registry. They are a bit tricky to find:

[image]

Of course, you have to restart the service after changing these settings.