# Elasticsearch startup error -- heap size

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jvm, heap-memory

on running

```
elasticsearch.bat
```

in Command Prompt,

I'm getting the error:

```
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms${packaging.elastic.heap.min}
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

The call:

```
elasticsearch -Xmx1g -Xms1g
```

among some others i tried with different parameters in place of 1GB didn't work either. 
[1GB is the default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html) anyways.

I'm running ES for the first time on this machine. This has been working fine 
till today-- when i invoked ES buy its batch caller

```
..>bin>elasticsearch.bat
```

it worked fine.

what am i missing?

TIA.

Note: i've see [Avoiding Initial Memory Heap Size Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909018/avoiding-initial-memory-heap-size-error), [Elasticsearch reports default heap memory size after setting environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128620/elasticsearch-reports-default-heap-memory-size-after-setting-environment-variabl) among some other relevant discussions.

Comment: I'm curious about the occurence of `${packaging.elastic.heap.min}` in your error message. Do you know where that comes from?

Comment: @Val checkout elasticsearch.bat, elasticsearch.in.bat in the bin directory. it's about the settings.

Comment: Tried a bunch of things with this and all failed.

Comment: Tried a bunch of things with this and all failed. Setting JAVA_OPTIONS to Xmx4g. Running with -Xmx1g flag. setting env variable to ES_HEAP_SIZE to something. Running javaw -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "InitialHeapSize" gives an answer 127926272. Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

in the file

elasticsearch-5.4.0/config/jvm.options

***comment
-Xms2g
-Xmx2g***

like this

#-Xms2g

#-Xmx2g

add

Xms4000m

Xmx4000m

**it works for me!!!**