# How to set memory limit to ElasticSearch in Windows?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any possible to limit ElasticSearch working set memory on a windows server 2008 R2?

I tried everything online, but nothing seem to work.

Tried to set (environment vars):
ES_MIN_MEM
ES_MAX_MEM
ES_HEAP_SIZE

In the java service:
-Xms15g
-Xmx15g
-Xss256k

In the YML file:
bootstrap.mlockall: true

Any idea what am I doing wrong, or if its possible at all to limit RAM in a Windows service?

Thanks!

Comment: `C:\elasticsearch\bin\service.bat manager elasticsearch-service-x64 manager elasticsearch-service-x64 → Java → Set "Maximum memory pool to 256 MB"`. Worked for me, but: 1) I'm on Win8.1 2) It still eats more (limit is there, but it's higher, something like 350MB).

Answer (score 61):

You can set the memory limit for Elastic Search on Windows Server by following command:

```
[Elasticsearch Path]\bin>elasticsearch-service.bat manager
```

Note: Run command prompt as administrator

It will open manager as shown here: [Image: ElasticSearch service properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gIQ3.png)

Now go to the 'Java' tab and change settings based on your requirement.

Note: Make sure, you changed it under 'JavaOptions' textbox and also for separate parameters. For example, to set 1GB initial memory pool and maximum memory pool, you can set '1024'  MB for both.

You can only use this manager after you install service. For more detail, refer  to the 'Using the Manager GUI' section at this link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/windows.html#windows

After your change, you need to restart the service. And, you can also see the change reflected in the registry as well under 'elasticsearch-service-x64' node:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\elasticsearch-service-x64\Parameters\Java
```

Note: It is mandatory to restart the service after any changes made in
manager properties window.

Comment: This answer was a life saver

Comment: For what it's worth, in my case, the BAT file was, simply, service.bat.

Comment: This is the only way to change the jvm options on Windows if running ES as a service from what I can tell.

Comment: While this lowered the RAM usage, it also made the service crash every time it started up.

Comment: I confirmed what @Cryptc said, if you lower the ```Initial memory pool``` to a number less than ```12800 MB``` it will crash!

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called `jvm.options` with lines like

```
-Xms4g
-Xmx8g
```

Then drop it to `$ELASTICHOME\config\jvm.options.d\`. Then restart ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit **C:\ProgramData\Elastic\ElastiSearch\config\jvm.option** file to change the size of JVM Heap (arguments: **-Xms15g** **-Xmx15g**), reducing the memory consumption.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the GUI manager described in the answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42906451/240398) that makes changes in the registry is the only way to change these settings on Windows when running as a service. Changes to jvm.options--at least for memory--don't matter.