# How to change the Elasticsearch ES_HEAP_SIZE on CentOS

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch 1.7.2 on CentOS, 8GB RAM

We see that `ES_HEAP_SIZE` should be increased to 4g.

The only place this seems declared in the ES environment is in `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch`

We set it to 4g in this init file, restarted ES, but the jvm `"heap_max_in_bytes"` (as returned from `/_nodes/stats` ) did not move from the default 1g value.

Where and how can we get control of `ES_HEAP_SIZE`  ?

(I should add: The similar looking threads here on SO are either dated [e.g. apply to earlier versions of ES and do not apply to 1.7.x] or are for other platforms [win, osx], or are do not work [have tried them, and you can see many of the responses are tagged 'this is a hack don't do it'])

(I should further note that the ES docs document this element, and suggest what to set it to, but do not instruct how or where.)

Comment: does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132719/how-to-change-elasticsearch-max-memory-size help? according to that you should look into `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch` .

Comment: @ChintanShah25 Yes, that is the ticket. It is rather buried in a comment on that thread. Posted it here in clear as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: Below is for Elasticsearch 1.7.x. For 5.3 and higher, it is different.**

Per a comment that is rather buried on [How to change Elasticsearch max memory size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18132719/147637)

On CentOS `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch` is the appropriate place to make these changes.

This has been tested and verified on my CentOS 7 environment. Strongly expect it to also fly on CentOS 6.