# How to run two versions of ElasticSearch with custom heap size on same server?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to run side by side two ElasticSearch instances (version 1.7 and version 5.2.2) on the same server (Widows 2012 R2). When I try to run the newer version, I receive an error:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Elasticsearch\elasticsearch-5.2.2\bin> .\elasticsearch.bat
Error: encountered environment variables that are no longer supported
Use jvm.options or ES_JAVA_OPTS to configure the JVM
ES_HEAP_SIZE=8g: set -Xms8g and -Xmx8g in jvm.options or add "-Xms8g -Xmx8g" to ES_JAVA_OPTS
```

This is caused by the fact that that there was a breaking change ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18132719/1108916)) in the way the heap size is set. In the previous version of ElasticSearch (1.7) it was set by an environment variable:

```
ES_HEAP_SIZE = 8g
```

I tried setting up another env variable:

```
ES_JAVA_OPTS = -Xms8g -Xmx8g
```

and I also edited `jvm.options` file by adding

```
-Xms8g
-Xmx8g
```

but I'm still getting the same error.

Is there a way to configure heap size in ElasticSearch 5.2.2 without deleting `ES_HEAP_SIZE` environment variable (which I need to keep version 1.7 up and running)? If not, is it possible to set heap size in the old version in a way that would also allow the new version to run?

Comment: Why don't you use docker?

Comment: Well, I'm currently installing docker and checking out the docs... I was hoping for an easier solution though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I found out:

it turns out that the error I was struggling with was raised not by ElasticSearch itself, but by the batch script running the ElasticSearch (`bin\elasticsearch.bat`). The problematic lines are:

```
if not "%ES_HEAP_SIZE%" == "" set bad_env_var=1
(...)
if %bad_env_var% == 1 (
    echo Error: encountered environment variables that are no longer supported
    echo Use jvm.options or ES_JAVA_OPTS to configure the JVM
    (...)
    if not "%ES_HEAP_SIZE%" == "" echo ES_HEAP_SIZE=%ES_HEAP_SIZE%: set -Xms%ES_HEAP_SIZE% and -Xmx%ES_HEAP_SIZE% in jvm.options or add "-Xms%ES_HEAP_SIZE% -Xmx%ES_HEAP_SIZE%" to ES_JAVA_OPTS
    (...)
    exit /b 1
)
```

As far as I can see, this check is there in order to help people migrating from older version to the newer, pointing them to a new way of setting up the heap size. Apart from that, the environment variable `ES_HEAP_SIZE` is not mentioned in the script, so its' existence should not affect the ElasticSearch 5.2.2 instance. Based on these observations, the easiest fix seems to be simply commenting out the check:

```
rem if not "%ES_HEAP_SIZE%" == "" set bad_env_var=1
```

I tried it and both instances of ElasticSearch now run side by side without issues.

*One additional trap to avoid is not to set up the heap size in both the file and `ES_JAVA_OPTS`, which leads to `duplicate min heap size settings found` error when deploying. Just stick to the file config.*

Huge thanks to @asettouf whose answer led me to the correct solution!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Given that jvm.options is not an option, the only thing I see is modifying your `elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch` script, mostly the line:

```
ES_JAVA_OPTS="$(parse_jvm_options "$ES_JVM_OPTIONS") $ES_JAVA_OPTS" #default
```

to:
    ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms myXmsValue -Xmx myXmxValue -someOtherOptions someValue"

With the other options and value according to what you want.

Comment: The file is actually in the `elasticsearch/config`, and I already tried editing it... But ES v5.2.2 still complains about the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` env var.

Comment: Then I would modify the launch script, see my edit (also good catch, it is indeed in the `config` folder) See my edited answer