# ElasticSearch: Changing default heap size

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I running Elasticsearch (version 2.x) on ubuntu. Single node cluster. By default, the max heap size is limited to 1GB. I have two more GBs to allocate for ES heap.

According to [official document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html):

1. Opened the file `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch` for editing.
2. I changed the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` variable of the file to "3gb" and saved the file.

> ES_HEAP_SIZE=3g

3. According to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132719/how-to-change-elasticsearch-max-memory-size), I also modified the security limits of the file `/etc/security/limits.conf` by adding those lines:

> elasticsearch - nofile 65535
>
> elasticsearch - memlock unlimited

4. called service restart `sudo service elasticsearch restart`

At this point, I'm expected to find that my ES node is consuming up to 3GB. I'm entered my kopf plugin (monitoring plugin) and saw that max heap size is 1GB (no changes).

[image]

What I missing? How to fix?

Comment: If you've installed elasticsearch using dep or rpm packages you should have a file at /etc/default/elasticsearch. I've managed to solve same issue by setting ES_Heap_Size in that file.

Comment: Exactly! this solved my problem!