# Elasticsearch 2.4 jvm.options ignored on MacOS Mojave (Homebrew install)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jvm, homebrew, elasticsearch-2.4

I've installed ElasticSearch 2.4 on my mac via HomeBrew. I'm trying to see if I can increase the JVM heap size for ElasticSearch.

I changed the following lines (to set the heap size to 8 gigs) in `/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`

```
-Xms8g
-Xmx8g
```

I then restart the service using `brew services restart elasticsearch@2.4` and run `curl localhost:9200/_nodes/stats/jvm?pretty` to check the JVM size but I get back:

```
"mem" : {
      "heap_used_in_bytes" : 144690472,
      "heap_used_percent" : 13,
      "heap_committed_in_bytes" : 259522560,
      "heap_max_in_bytes" : 1038876672,
      "non_heap_used_in_bytes" : 62484680,
      "non_heap_committed_in_bytes" : 65093632,
      ...
```

Why are my `Xms8g` and `Xmx8g` flags being ignored in `jvm.options`, and what should I do to make elsaticsearch respect them?

I've been basing my actions on: [How to change Elasticsearch max memory size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132719/how-to-change-elasticsearch-max-memory-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

You need to change the environment variables passed through the `plist` used to launch elasticsearch.

In `/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch@2.4/2.4.6/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch@2.4.plist`, under the `<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>` key, add:

```
<dict>
  <key>ES_HEAP_SIZE</key>
  <string>2g</string>
</dict>
```

Beware, there's another `plist` that exists in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist`. Changing this does nothing since it gets overwritten by `brew services` on restart.

Also of note, there are two `jvm.options` files to do with ElasticSearch visible on your system:

- `/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch@2.4/2.4.6/libexec/config`
- `/usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`

It looks like one of these is just a symlink to the other, and changing the memory flags in either of them does absolutely nothing.